# Unable to install pyodbc on Linux

Tags: python, linux, centos, pyodbc

I am running Linux (2.6.18-164.15.1.el5.centos.plus) and trying to install pyodbc.  I am doing pip install pyodbc and get a very long list of errors, which end in

> error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

I looked in  **/root/.pip/pip.log** and saw the following:

> InstallationError: Command /usr/local/bin/python -c "import setuptools; **file**='/home/build/pyodbc/setup.py'; execfile('/home/build/pyodbc/setup.py')" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-7MS9Vu-record/install-record.txt failed with error code 1

Has anybody had a similar issue installing pyodbc?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I resolved my issue by following correct directions on [pyodbc - Building wiki](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Building) which states:

> On Linux, pyodbc is typically built using the unixODBC headers, so you will need unixODBC and its headers installed. On a RedHat/CentOS/Fedora box, this means you would need to install unixODBC-devel:
>
> ```
> yum install unixODBC-devel
> ```

Comment: It fails for me...SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "/usr/libexec/urlgrabber-ext-down", line 28
    except OSError, e:
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


Exiting on user cancel

Comment: @famargar You upgraded you Linux distro?

Comment: I am using Centos 7 and Linux 3.10.0-957.5.1.el7.x86_64. Are they known to have issues with pyodbc?

Answer (score 239):

On Ubuntu, you'll need to install unixodbc-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev
```

Install pip by using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

once that is installed, you should be able to install pyodbc successfully:

```
pip install pyodbc
```

Comment: I needed to install python-devel too before this worked for me.

Comment: Yesssss!!! this was the fifth solution I used and the one that worked, thank you :)

Comment: That worked! I got an error "Can't find package", but running sudo apt-get update first fixed it.

Comment: For python 3.7 on Ubuntu additionally run `sudo apt-get install python3.7-dev`

Answer (score 43):

Adding one more answer on this question.
For **Linux Debian Stretch** release you would need to install the following dependencies:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install unixodbc-dev
pip install pyodbc
```

On **Debian Slim** some users mentioned they needed to add g++

```
apt-get update
apt-get install g++ unixodbc-dev
pip install pyodbc
```

Comment: On Debian Slim image I needed to include g++ before I could install pyodbc.

Comment: @Snympi Yep, that's why the commands above include `apt-get install g++` ;)

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer works on my Debian GNU/Linux 9, the g++ is negligible though.

Comment: I also needed g++ for Ubuntu 20.04. Thanks

Comment: the specification for DEBIAN SLIM it's a gem!

Answer (score 18):

Struggled with the same issue

After running: 
`sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev`

I was able to pip install pyodbc

Comment: This worked for me with python 3.7 on circleci's image.

Answer (score 17):

Follow below steps to install pyodbc in any redhat version

```
yum install unixODBC unixODBC-devel
yum install gcc-c++
yum install python-devel
pip install pyodbc
```

Answer (score 9):

I have referenced this question several times, and gone on to actually find the answer I was looking for here:
[pyodbc wiki](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Building)

> To avoid gcc error on Ubuntu Linux, I did:
>
> ```
> sudo aptitude install g++
> ```
>
> I also installed the following 2 packages from Synaptic:
>
> - python-dev
> - tdsodbc

Comment: Or if you're on an Ubuntu:
`sudo apt-get install g++`
After that, I was able to pip install into my venv. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Execute the following commands (tested on centos 6.5):

```
yum install install unixodbc-dev
yum install gcc-c++
yum install python-devel
pip install --allow-external pyodbc --allow-unverified pyodbc pyodbc
```

Answer (score 8):

According to [official Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) for Ubuntu 18.04 you should run next commands:

```
sudo su 
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
apt-get update
ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17
exit
```

If you are using python3.7, it is very important to run:

`sudo apt-get install python3.7-dev`

Comment: Thank you. "pip3 install pyodbc" worked after the installation of the msodbc via official documantation on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 4):

A easy way to install pyodbc is by using 'conda'. As conda automatically installs required dependencies including unixodbc.

`conda --ugrade all` (optional)

then 
`conda install pyodbc`

it will install following packages:

`libgfortran-ng: 7.2.0-hdf63c60_3              defaults
    mkl:            2018.0.3-1                    defaults
    mkl_fft:        1.0.2-py36_0                  conda-forge
    mkl_random:     1.0.1-py36_0                  conda-forge
    numpy-base:     1.14.5-py36hdbf6ddf_0         defaults
    pyodbc:         4.0.17-py36_0                 conda-forge
    unixodbc:       2.3.4-1                       conda-forge`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem on CentOS 5.5

In addition to installing unixODBC-devel I also had to install gcc-c++

```
yum install gcc-c++
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case (**Amazon Linux AMI**) none of the above worked. The following worked (idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36353331/2445273)):

- Find the path to the file `cc1plus`. For me it was in `/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-amazon-linux/4.8.5/cc1plus`. For you it may vary a bit. Try `ls -l /usr/libexec/gcc` to find the proper directory name and go ahead.
- Find directories in your path: `echo $PATH` (for me it was `/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/aws/bin`)
- Put a link to `cc1plus` in one of the directories in your PATH:  `sudo ln -s /PATH/TO/cc1plus /DIRinPATH/`
  For example in my case:
  `sudo ln -s /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-amazon-linux/4.8.5/cc1plus  /usr/bin/`

Comment: Have you tried maybe to get unixODBC+FreeTDS run on AWS Lambda?

Answer (score 1):

I needed all that, but I also needed python devel installed:

```
sudo yum install python-devel
```

Answer (score 1):

How about installing pyobdc from zip file? From [How to connect to Microsoft Sql Server from Ubuntu using pyODBC](http://zxtech.wordpress.com/2013/06/23/how-to-connect-to-microsoft-sql-server-from-ubuntu-using-pyodbc/):

> **Download source vs apt-get**
>
> The apt-get utility in Ubuntu does have a version of pyODBC. (version 2.1.7).
> However, it is badly out-of-date (2.1.7 vs 3.0.6) and may not work well with the newer versions of unixODBC and freetds.
> This is especially important if you are trying to connect to later versions of Microsoft Sql Server (2008 onwards).
> It is recommended that you use the latest versions of unixODBC, freetds and pyODBC when working with the latest Microsoft Sql Server instead of relying on packages in apt-get.

Comment: compilation terminated. error: command 'i686-linuxgnu-gccc' failed with exit status 1

Comment: warning: command line option ä-Wstrict-prototypes' is valid for c/Objc but not for C++  [enabled by default]

Comment: apt-get install aptitude         aptitude install g++              apt-get install python-dev       python ./setup.py install

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but the maintainer has a [`pyodbc` GitHub Repo](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Install).

I also found a [very good example for installing FreeTDS and setting up the config files](http://www.stevepiercy.com/articles/how-to-install-and-configure-freetds-as-an-odbc-connector-to-microsoft-sql-server-on-centosrhel-for-lasso-9/).

---

Following the instructions on the GitHub docs seems to me to always be the best option.  As of February, 2018, for CentOs7 (they have all flavors at the link) they say:

```
# Add the RHEL 6 library for Centos-7 of MSSQL driver. Centos7 uses RHEL-6 Libraries.
sudo su 
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/6/prod.repo > /etc/yum.repos.d/mssql-release.repo
exit

# Uninstall if already installed Unix ODBC driver
sudo yum remove unixODBC-utf16 unixODBC-utf16-devel #to avoid conflicts

# Install the  msodbcsql unixODBC-utf16 unixODBC-utf16-devel driver
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y yum install msodbcsql

#optional: for bcp and sqlcmd
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y yum install mssql-tools
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc

# optional: for unixODBC development headers
sudo yum install unixODBC-devel

# the Microsoft driver expects unixODBC to be here /usr/lib64/libodbc.so.1, so add soft links to the '.so.2' files
cd /usr/lib64
sudo ln -s libodbccr.so.2   libodbccr.so.1
sudo ln -s libodbcinst.so.2 libodbcinst.so.1
sudo ln -s libodbc.so.2     libodbc.so.1

# Set the path for unixODBC
export ODBCINI=/usr/local/etc/odbc.ini
export ODBCSYSINI=/usr/local/etc
source ~/.bashrc

# Prepare a temp file for defining the DSN to your database server
vi /home/user/odbcadd.txt

[MyMSSQLServer]
Driver      = ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
Description = My MS SQL Server
Trace       = No
Server      = 10.100.1.10

# register the SQL Server database DSN information in /etc/odbc.ini
sudo odbcinst -i -s -f /home/user/odbcadd.txt -l

# check the DSN installation with:
odbcinst -j
cat /etc/odbc.ini

# should contain a section called [MyMSSQLServer]

# install the python driver for database connection
pip install pyodbc
```

Comment: Hi Shubham, I'm sorry, I don't understand your question.  After typing `pip install pyodbc`, assuming everything else went OK, you will have both the driver and the package installed and available.  You would "simply use" the package, creating the connection object and the cursor similar to any other programmatic access to a DB.  You can look at [their documentation](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki) for examples.

Answer (score 1):

For archlinux/manjaro:

```
sudo pacman -S unixodbc
```

then:

```
sudo pip install pyodbc
```

or:

```
pip install pyodbc
```

You can upgrade your pip wheel setuptools before installing pyodbc (it won't affect the pyodbc installation) also with:

```
sudo python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
```

or

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
yum install unixODBC.x86_64
```

Depending on the version of centos could change the package, you can search like this:

```
yum search unixodbc
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced with same issue. For python3.6.8 and ubuntu 16.04 none of above did not help me.

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev
```

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.11-alpine

# install dependencies (g++ is required for pyodbc)
RUN apk update && apk add postgresql-dev gcc g++ unixodbc-dev python3-dev curl bash sudo
```

The above Dockerfile works for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I have unixodbc, unixodbc-dev and python3-dev all installed, but I still get

```
      In file included from src/buffer.cpp:12:
      src/pyodbc.h:56:10: fatal error: sql.h: No such file or directory
         56 | #include <sql.h>
            |          ^~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
```

gcc and g++ are installed as well.

I'm running pop-os 22.10.  I've also checked that odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini exist as well and have FreeTDS installed.

Comment: ok, found out the issue for me. For some reason PyCharm 2022.1.0 refused to deal with python3.10. The python terminal said 3.10, but the virtualenv always reset to 3.9.9.

I reinstalled and got 2022.1.1 and it had no issue with 3.10 and pyodbc installed without a hitch.

For those using Pycharm and pop-os, DO NOT install from the pop shop. The updates refused to work and via pycharm it has a permission error.

Either way, what was happening was I was trying to install pyodbc with python3.9.9, but the system version of python was 3.10. This caused the compiler to have a fit