# gcc cannot find cc1plus

Tags: python, gcc, pandas, centos

I'm trying to install the python package pandas on CentOS 6 but I'm having problems with the gcc compiler:

```
sudo pip install pandas
...    
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/msgpack

gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -D__LITTLE_ENDIAN__=1 -Ipandas/src/msgpack -Ipandas/src/klib -Ipandas/src -I/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/include/python2.7 -c pandas/msgpack/_packer.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/msgpack/_packer.o -Wno-unused-function

gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
...
```

So it appears I need cc1plus, which by reading around requires gcc-g++. But I already have gcc-c++:

```
sudo yum install gcc-c++
...
Package gcc-c++-4.4.7-16.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

About gcc and cc1plus:

```
gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)

which gcc
/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/gcc

locate cc1plus
/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/cc1plus
```

*My own solution below. Does anybody have better ways of addressing the problem?*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solution to my own question:
It seems that cc1plus, although present, is not visible to gcc as it is not on path. So a solution is to link cc1plus to a directory on PATH:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/cc1plus /usr/local/bin/
```

Now `sudo pip install pandas` succeeds.

(But why the package manager put `cc1plus` there in the first place?)

Comment: This helps in a pinch, sure. But one should look into whether or not they have multiple versions of `gcc` installed. This happened to me when `gcc72` was added by Salt around midnight earlier today. I had a state file on my Jenkins instance with `yum groupinstall Development Tools` and gcc 7.2.1 happened to be added to the list of packages when Salt was set to run. A quick look under `/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-amazon-linux/7` will show that `cc1plus` is not available with this version. Meanwhile, `/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-amazon-linux/4.8.5` did, in fact, have `cc1plus` present.

Comment: @Sergio thank you for you comment. it saved my sanity.

Comment: Yeah this isn't the cleanest way to fix this. Manually installing symlinks to binaries is asking for trouble in the future.