# pyodbc install on IBM Bluemix server error

Tags: python, flask, ibm-cloud, azure-sql-database, pyodbc

I am trying to host my app on IBM bluemix. In my app, I have used flask and I am trying to Connect to Azure SQL Server database. So for that, I am using Pyodbc.

So in `requirement.txt` file I have given 
`pip install pyodbc`
and 
`pip install flask`. 
These things are getting installed on my local machine and the app is running fine. I am getting the result from the database .

But when I am trying to deploy my application on IBM bluemix,
while pushing the files on the server it is giving me an error. 
I have attached the error screenshot below.

The content of requirement.txt is here

```
unixodbc-dev
pyodbc==3.1.1
Flask==0.12.2
```

[image: Error Message]

Comment: The environment is linux that is defined by a cloud foundry buildpack: http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/python/.  You don't have access to install package inside the environment such as unixODBC.  I'm looking to see if there is an alternative buildpack that contains unixODBC.

Comment: @ChrisSnow these are the contents of my requirement.txt            
`unixodbc-dev
pyodbc==3.1.1
Flask==0.12.2`

Comment: I've created a more specific question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44982510/fatal-error-sql-h-with-unixodbc-and-pyodbc-as-a-vendor-app-dependency

Comment: @ChrisSnow thank you i will keep track of it

Comment: @ChrisSnow thank you i will keep track of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use miniconda to install your dependencies instead of pip.  Using miniconda with the buildpack is documented [here](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/python/#miniconda).

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44982510/fatal-error-sql-h-with-unixodbc-and-pyodbc-as-a-vendor-app-dependency) for more information on using miniconda to install pyodbc.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried that solution . my app is getting deployed on server now and I am getting no error. While running that app on bluemix server i am getting this error  `pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")` I am posting my code in aap.py file in next comment

Comment: This is my code for which i am getting this error. This code is working on my local machine. but giving above error on bluemix. `@app.route('/sql/<lat>/<long>') 
def api_sql(lat,long):
 cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=prashantvikramsingh.database.windows.net;DATABASE=Zillow;UID=prashant;PWD=Pvs758993@')
 cursor = cnxn.cursor()
 cursor.execute("SELECT top 10 * FROM [dbo].[distance] ("+lat+","+long+") order by distance")
 rows = cursor.fetchall()`

Comment: Have a look at this question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38534154/linux-python3-cant-open-lib-sql-server.  If that doesn't solve your problem, I suggest you accept this answer to your original question and then create a new question.

Answer (score -1):

The error message `error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1` makes it seem like perhaps you need to install the gcc C/C++ compiler on that machine.

[The pyodbc docs say](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyodbc/wikis/Building.wiki):

> Windows
>
> On Windows, you will need the appropriate Microsoft Visual C++ compiler. To build Python 2.4 or 2.5 versions, you will need the Visual Studio 2003 .NET compiler. Unfortunately there is no free version of this.
>
> For Python 2.6 and above, you can use the free Visual C++ 2008 Express compiler. (Do not use the 2010 version! You need to use the version that your Python distribution was built with.)
>
> You can create a Windows installer using: python setup.py bdist_wininst
>
> Other
>
> To build on other operating systems, use the gcc compiler.
>
> On Linux, pyodbc is typically built using the unixODBC headers, so you will need unixODBC and its headers installed. On a RedHat/CentOS/Fedora box, this means you would need to install unixODBC-devel:
>
> yum install unixODBC-devel

---

Related: [Unable to install pyodbc on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960339/unable-to-install-pyodbc-on-linux)

Comment: how do i install these things? Do i have to write them in requirement.txt  I tried putting unixODBC-devel and gcc-c++.

Comment: You install it from the command line.  If your OS is Ubuntu, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9087394/4115031) suggests running `sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev`.

Comment: i am using windows and not getting the command for windows. tried installing it using pip but it says package not found

Comment: pyodbc is installed on my local machine and running fine. When i try to host the app on IBM bluemix it is giving that error

Comment: Are you sure your Bluemix server is running Windows? It looks from your error like your server is running Linux.